# Clustering bubbles in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to do a widget with some information from Google Analytics. I am getting the real time visitors and then displaying them in bubbles with flags with the help of d3.js. I do manage to get them on the screen and the force simulation is working properly. However I can't seem to grasp how could I cluster the bubbles according to their respective country, as I don't know which countries will be displayed in advance, and I'm not good at web programming so as do some on the fly links and use the forceLink. Maybe there is a better way that I'm missing? I would greatly appreciate any pointers that you could give me.

```js
(function() {
  var width = 500;
  height = 500;

  var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")



  // SO question preparation :
  var data_csv = "Country,Count\nUkraine,1\nDenmark,1\nDenmark,1";



  data = d3.csvParse(data_csv);

  d3.queue().await(ready, data);


  var forceX = d3.forceX(function(d) {
    return width / 2
  }).strength(0.05)



  var forceY = d3.forceY(function(d) {
    return height / 2
  }).strength(0.05)


  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("xTowardsTheCenter", forceX)
    .force("yTowardsTheCenter", forceY)
    .force("antiColliding", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
      return radiusScale(d.Count) + 1;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-15))


  // this function sets up a variation scale so that the circles can have different sizes without
  // occupying all of the screen

  var radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([1, 40]).range([30, 130]);



  function ready(error, datapoints) {

    var circles = svg.selectAll(".Country")
      .data(datapoints)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d.Country;
      })
      .attr("class", "country")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return radiusScale(d.Count);
      })
      .attr("text", function(d) {
        return d.Count;
      })
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", "blue")



    simulation.nodes(datapoints)
      .on('tick', ticked)

    function ticked() {
      circles
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y
        })
    }


})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Neets visitors </title>
        <b>Neets visitors</b>
        <body>
            <div id="chart"></div>
            <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
            <script src="bubble.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojpQh.png)

Comment: First make your code snippet run.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how to direct my html to my javascript snippet in the Code Snippet. Nor how could I point towards a .csv file in it... should I use an online drive and direct my script there? Sorry first time posting...

Comment: include the CSV content hard in your code with **Template literals**, use d3.csvParse, or supply a full URL to the CSV loader. You also have to find a way to supply the `Flags/xxxx.svg` files or replace with a color pattern. The javascript part is implicit included in the running `iframe`

Comment: I have added a div tag with id=chart to the html